# how to convert hours minute second to decimal number

Tags: c#

How to convert hour, minute, second format to a decimal number?
I want calculate faculty salary with his working time. So I need to find his working time. So I got the working time in the time format. ii need to convert that time format to a decimal number. I wrote this code but I did not get the answer.
`decimal a = Common.CD(txttotal.Text);`

Comment: So `hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + second`?

Comment: Supposedly, you have some text in txttotal editfield to start with, right? What does this text actually mean? Is this an amount of something? Some date? Something else? Please clarify.

Comment: sir ...i have start time field and end time filed when i subtract end time from start time i got  time format like 1:00:00 .so i want to convert that format to decimal number .in c#

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSpan.TotalHours` might be what you are looking for. Example:

```
var test = new TimeSpan(4, 30, 0);
Console.WriteLine(test.TotalHours); // 4.5
```

If you need to convert a text to a `TimeSpan`, use `TimeSpan.Parse(...)`:

```
string text = "04:30:00";
TimeSpan test = TimeSpan.Parse(text);
```

The method in your case should look like this:

```
public static string CS (TimeSpan duration)
{
    return Math.Round(duration.TotalHours, 2).ToString();
}
```

I added some rounding to hide inaccuracy while calculating `TimeSpan` and `TotalHours`.

Comment: DateTime startTime=Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerAdv1.Value);DateTime endtime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerAdv2.Value);
            if (startTime > endtime)
            {     TimeSpan duration = startTime - endtime;                           
                txttotal.Text = Common.CS(duration);
            }
            else
            {
                TimeSpan duration =  endtime- startTime;
                txttotal.Text = Common.CS(duration);
            }I execute this code but i cant convert it in to decimal number.i want to display decimal number in the txttotal .text

Comment: I edited my answer. If that still did not work, please specify what you mean by saying "i can't convert it into decimal number"